# Why does this code generate all 1s in the result instead of a mixture of 0s and 1s?

Tags: c

I've created a 64*64 size hadamard matrix of characters and would now like to pass the binary values of each row of the matrix (i.e. a 64 bit binary number) into an array (lookup). The code to do this is the double for loop at the bottom of the main function.

Using the code here when I execute a list of ones are printed, instead of the full binary value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void create_hadamard_matrix(char** h, int N)
{
    int ind,indr,indc;

    for (ind=1;ind<=N;ind*=2)
    {

        // find the half length of H matrix for this iteration
        int sideHalf=ind/2;

        //for n=1 H matrix
        if (ind==1)
        {
            h[0][0]='1';
        }
        else
        {
            //put in values in bottom left of new H matrix
            for (indr=0; indr<sideHalf; indr++)
            {
                for (indc=0; indc<sideHalf; indc++)
                {
                    h[indr+sideHalf][indc]=h[indr][indc];
                }
            }
            //put in values in top right of new H matrix
            for (indr=0; indr<sideHalf; indr++)
            {
                for (indc=0; indc<sideHalf; indc++)
                {
                    h[indr][indc+sideHalf]=h[indr][indc];
                }
            }
            //put in values in bottom right of new H matrix
            for (indr=0; indr<sideHalf; indr++)
            {
                for (indc=0; indc<sideHalf; indc++)
                {
                    //invert characters
                    if (h[indr][indc]=='1')
                    {
                        h[indr+sideHalf][indc+sideHalf]='0';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        h[indr+sideHalf][indc+sideHalf]='1';
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


void main()
{
    int i,j,N=64;

    char **h = (char**) malloc(N  * sizeof(char*));
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        h[i] = (char*) malloc(N  * sizeof(char));
    }

    create_hadamard_matrix(h, N);

    unsigned long long *lookup = (unsigned long long*) malloc(N * sizeof(unsigned long long));

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            if (h[i][j]=='1')
            {
                lookup[i]=(1<<(63-j));
            }   

        }
        printf("%llu",lookup[i]);   
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: For N = 64, you'd do better to write `unsigned long long lookup[N];` instead of using `malloc()`.  Ideally (though it won't really matter in this code), you should be able to point to the call to `free()` that releases the memory allocated by each call to `malloc()` et al.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `main()` (which should return an `int`, btw), change this:

```
if (h[i][j]='1');
```

To this:

```
if (h[i][j]=='1')
```

for hopefully obvious reasons.

---

Next, your lookup array is not being initialized after allocation (and though you may not think it need be, it is required for the next error fix after this to work):

Change this:

```
unsigned long long *lookup = (unsigned long long*) malloc(N * sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

To this:

```
unsigned long long *lookup = calloc(N, sizeof(*lookup));
```

which will zero-fill the lookup array on inception. You could also `memset` if you wanted to. The choice is yours.

---

And next, you're overwriting your lookup value for each row for multiple bits. I.e. the *last* bit you write into any row's lookup entry is the *only* one that is saved. You need to accumulate them using `|=` rather than just `=`. Also, you need to ensure the shift-operation is done on a ulonglong. As written it is shifting on an `int` well-beyond the `int` width. See below.

Change this:

```
lookup[i]=(1<<(63-j));
```

To this:

```
lookup[i]|=(((unsigned long long)1)<<(63-j));
```

Putting that all together and using a bit-printer I just slammed out, this is what I get:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010
1100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100
1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001
1111000011110000111100001111000011110000111100001111000011110000
1010010110100101101001011010010110100101101001011010010110100101
1100001111000011110000111100001111000011110000111100001111000011
1001011010010110100101101001011010010110100101101001011010010110
1111111100000000111111110000000011111111000000001111111100000000
1010101001010101101010100101010110101010010101011010101001010101
1100110000110011110011000011001111001100001100111100110000110011
1001100101100110100110010110011010011001011001101001100101100110
1111000000001111111100000000111111110000000011111111000000001111
1010010101011010101001010101101010100101010110101010010101011010
1100001100111100110000110011110011000011001111001100001100111100
1001011001101001100101100110100110010110011010011001011001101001
1111111111111111000000000000000011111111111111110000000000000000
1010101010101010010101010101010110101010101010100101010101010101
1100110011001100001100110011001111001100110011000011001100110011
1001100110011001011001100110011010011001100110010110011001100110
1111000011110000000011110000111111110000111100000000111100001111
1010010110100101010110100101101010100101101001010101101001011010
1100001111000011001111000011110011000011110000110011110000111100
1001011010010110011010010110100110010110100101100110100101101001
1111111100000000000000001111111111111111000000000000000011111111
1010101001010101010101011010101010101010010101010101010110101010
1100110000110011001100111100110011001100001100110011001111001100
1001100101100110011001101001100110011001011001100110011010011001
1111000000001111000011111111000011110000000011110000111111110000
1010010101011010010110101010010110100101010110100101101010100101
1100001100111100001111001100001111000011001111000011110011000011
1001011001101001011010011001011010010110011010010110100110010110
1111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000
1010101010101010101010101010101001010101010101010101010101010101
1100110011001100110011001100110000110011001100110011001100110011
1001100110011001100110011001100101100110011001100110011001100110
1111000011110000111100001111000000001111000011110000111100001111
1010010110100101101001011010010101011010010110100101101001011010
1100001111000011110000111100001100111100001111000011110000111100
1001011010010110100101101001011001101001011010010110100101101001
1111111100000000111111110000000000000000111111110000000011111111
1010101001010101101010100101010101010101101010100101010110101010
1100110000110011110011000011001100110011110011000011001111001100
1001100101100110100110010110011001100110100110010110011010011001
1111000000001111111100000000111100001111111100000000111111110000
1010010101011010101001010101101001011010101001010101101010100101
1100001100111100110000110011110000111100110000110011110011000011
1001011001101001100101100110100101101001100101100110100110010110
1111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111
1010101010101010010101010101010101010101010101011010101010101010
1100110011001100001100110011001100110011001100111100110011001100
1001100110011001011001100110011001100110011001101001100110011001
1111000011110000000011110000111100001111000011111111000011110000
1010010110100101010110100101101001011010010110101010010110100101
1100001111000011001111000011110000111100001111001100001111000011
1001011010010110011010010110100101101001011010011001011010010110
1111111100000000000000001111111100000000111111111111111100000000
1010101001010101010101011010101001010101101010101010101001010101
1100110000110011001100111100110000110011110011001100110000110011
1001100101100110011001101001100101100110100110011001100101100110
1111000000001111000011111111000000001111111100001111000000001111
1010010101011010010110101010010101011010101001011010010101011010
1100001100111100001111001100001100111100110000111100001100111100
1001011001101001011010011001011001101001100101101001011001101001
```

Hopefully that is what its supposed to look like (honestly I haven't a clue).

Comment: Remove the semicolon too.

Comment: I make the changes, the list is still mostly ones, but with a few other numbers interspersed in between (i.e. 1 2 4 1 16 etc). I was hoping to get a 64 bit binary number, any idea why it's not working?

Comment: What is it you want? You mean something like 101101001010... etc? You'll have to write a translation function for that. `printf()` won't do it natively. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that, ill fix that bit later. However the numbers are still incorrect, i.e. the top row of the h matrix is all ones so the decimal should be 295147905179352825840, but it prints as just 1.

Comment: @Bob Sorry, but isn't a fully lit 64-bit unsigned 18446744073709551615 ? (i.e. 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) ? (and I think I know what the problem is regardless)

Comment: Yes it is, I put a zero onto the end of the number in the converter accidentally. What is the problem?

Comment: @Bob Read the updated answer. That should spell it out for you. Had a few typos I had to address. Terribly sorry about that.

Comment: @WhozCraig didn't you ment calloc instead of malloc ?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the updated answer. When I replaced The matrix allocation with the suggested code I got the error 'too many arguments to function malloc', however it worked with the original setup.

Comment: @Bob if it does its by chance. `malloc()` doesn't zero-initialize the allocation content, so you need to either follow it with a `memset()` to zero for the same number of bytes, or just use the `calloc()` call I updated in the answer. But you need to do one or the other.